# Creating ArrayList from class

Tags: java, android, arrays

I've been building simple card game, player will have 3 cards.
i have this cardPart class and i want to create array list from it

```
 public List<CardParts> parts = new ArrayList<CardParts>();

 parts.add(new CardParts());   //<== error here, i don't know how to make it array
```

my cardparts class :

```
public class CardParts {

public CardParts(String[] picz) {


}

}
```

i need to use array , so i can easily use the for loop and enter random number for each increment.. for example : `parts[i] = randomnumber;`

if you confuse, simply this, 
the plan is i need 3 cards , with each card can keep 11 data (array)
`card1 = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,A)` , so on the other card <-- just like that..

please help me solve it with arraylist thing if you could.. , however if stuck, i am willing to use other method.. ,

thank you

Comment: the reason why there's an error, because you don't have a default constructor in the class CardParts (just with `String[]` as parameter). But what's exactly your question?

Comment: i don't know yet what to write in its constructor :( , all i want to do is to get the "part" is in array , so i can access it using parts(i) = something; or somewhere in loop , parts[i].get(i) , like that.  i hope you get what i am trying to say here.. :(

Comment: `parts[i].get(i)` won't work because an `ArrayList` *is not an array*. It's an object that wraps an array, which means that you can't use array specific syntax with it. `parts.get(i)[i]` would work, because the left hand side of the expression (`parts.get(i)`) *is* an array. It's a dangerous operation to perform though, as you risk an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` by doing things that way.

Comment: oohh, so what to use then now ? . can't i make 3 objects (3 cards in my case) and each one of the objects has array value ?

Comment: Your `Card` objects can *contain* an array, but they won't *be* arrays themselves. Arrays are a special kind of object which you create using the `[]` syntax. `Card[] cards` would declare an array containing `Card` objects, but each element wouldn't be an array itself. However, each `Card` could *contain* an array (which is known as **composition**).

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to use the default no-argument constructor of an object when you have defined an argumented constructor. If you define a constructor, the compiler no longer generates a no-args constructor for you (but you can still define a no-args constructor yourself).

Either you need to define a no-argument constructor in your `CardParts` class, or you need to pass in a `String[]` to the constructor so that it matches `CardParts(String[])`.

You should probably give [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) a read.